# Deploy Spring boot angular app to Kubernetes using docker, but it is unaccessible

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a Spring boot angular app called 'myapp' containing two microservice - 'admin' and 'user'. Admin is set to port 8081 while user is set to the port 8080.

When I deploy to docker, everything seems fine. But when I try to deploy it to Azure Kubernetes. Although it is deployed, but nothing is showed in my website. Attached the deployment.yaml and service.yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tablehop-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: tablehopapp
  ports:
    - name: admin
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
    - name: user
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tablehopapp-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: tablehopapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

[Unaccesible website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW8dG.png)

Comment: how do you connect that IP in the screenshot to your kubernetes cluster? Have your created a `LoadBalancer` service anywhere inside the cluster?